# NullPointerExcepcion creating object

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a class that I have made serializable and that I go from one activity to another, but in one of them, despite the fact that the code is copied from the others that DOES work, it gives me the error of NullPointerExcepcion

I write the code:

***The class***

```
public class Plan implements Serializable {

    int id;
    String usuario;
    int tipo;

  public Plan()
    {
         id=-1;
         usuario ="";
         tipo=-1;
}

//SETTER and GETTERS

}
```

**The Activity**

```
    public class NuevoAvaInf extends Activity {
    
        private Plan miPlan;
        EditText veh,apar,notas;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_ava_inf);
    
            miPlan = new Plan();
            miPlan = (Plan)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miPlan");
    
    Log.i("DEPURAR","Comprobar miPlan:"+miPlan.getId()+" \n");
...
}
```

**The error:**
The line it points to is: `Log.i ("DEBUG", "Check myPlan:" + myPlan.getId () + "\ n");`

> /AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{midlab.safeplan/midlab.safeplan.NuevoAvaInf}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Show the code which sends (sets) the intent.

Comment: i've wrote the solution, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that in the previous activity there is no pass through putExtra the data.

I leave the code that fatlaba:

passIntent.putExtra ("myPlan", myPlan);